# searching records from multiple databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have more than 10 databases with same tables but different records.

Now I would like to have a search engine that can search all the databases. Let say for example I am going to search for a person by last name or first name, then the search must go to all of the databases, the query will search all the databases.

How can i do that?..

Do you have sample code for ASP.NET C#? thanks!

Comment: You *probably* do not want a single query that traverses all the databases, though technically that is possible.  Why do you not want to go with the straightforward solution and simply hit each database in turn?

Comment: because it is more efficient ,but I don't know how to do.. I can search using single database but not multiple.

Comment: Well, it's more "efficient", but then you're offloading all the RPC'ing to the database server.   Usually it's preferable to have your app servers take ownership of that task, so you don't overburden your database with superfluous intercommunication.  Anyway, to help you any further, you'll have to specify your *particular* database.

Comment: Are linked/federated servers not an option here?

Comment: @KirkWoll for example I have this databases: LMS-PHI,LMS-AUS,LMS-US,LMS-HK,LMS-SPA...databases have the same tables , stored procedures and indexes but they have different records.  if I am going to create a page that search for a member name, the query must search all the databases for that member name by using stored procedures and web service..

Comment: @Dhenn, and what database server are you using?  (Also, you should see how bad the default implementation would be.  I think that's the best one anyway, and there's no-matter-what going to be a cost for hitting every sever.  I think you can write code that does this job efficiently and, perhaps more importantly, can scale horizonatally in a way that is difficult with db servers)

Comment: Do'es each of your database requires a different connection(string)?

Comment: @Dhenn as Kirk mentioned it would be nice to know if these DBs live on the same server and what type of DB platform you are using.

Comment: Are all the databases on same server? if not then you have to create linked servers

Comment: @KirkWoll we are using sql server 2000, the databases are live on different servers

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Dhenn create a view in your one database by union on the 10 tables 
and you can get easy search on that

table1 is in database1 and table2 is in database2
then

```
 select * from  database1.dbo.table1. 
union all

 select * from  database2.dbo.table1. 

.
.
.
```

other option you can fire 10 hits to 10 databases from asp.net c#
and then merge result and show on screen.

Please Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594256/ms-sql-server-2000multiple-database-query)

Comment: it only shows tables in the database, it doesn't show the tables on other databases

Comment: just a minor correction in the query it should be  (database2.dbo.table2) in second union.   select * from  database1.dbo.table1. 
union all

 select * from  database2.dbo.table1.